# Eclipse not starting, exit code 13

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse has just recently stopped starting correctly. This is the screen it gives:
[image]

Not sure what's changed since the last time it worked properly.
This is my ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: The accepted answer in the question I linked might not solve your problem, but there are many comments that maybe could (i.e. ADTC's comment about Java 7 vs 8 / 32-bit vs 64-bit)

Comment: Download and reinstall/reunpack Eclipse. If you're guessing at what's changed, we're only going to be guessing at how to fix it. In general, don't put Eclipse under Program Files. Strange things happen with permissions there, and exit code 13 is a general code for something being "wrong" with the JRE.

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse and a 32 bit Java. They must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using 64 bit eclipse and 32 bit jvm or vice-versa.